# Output List content using ICEFaces

Tags: list, formatting, tags, icefaces

I want to show a List using ICEFaces, and I want to output it like:
    `TAG1, TAG2, TAG3.`

But without using , or <% for (...) { ... } %>, is there a way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ICEfaces doesn't provide any mechanism for putting "logic" inside views (the rendered property is the only kind-of way).

However, I would propose you to take a look at two other JSF tags: **c:forEach** and **ui:repeat**

You'll find them in the following two namespaces:

```
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
```

There are fundamental differences, since c:forEach is a TagHandler and ui:repeat a Component. It will basically depend on the content you want to output within the *loop*, which way you choose. They'll be evaluated at different phases when the view is built.

I'd recommend a blog post by Roger Keays which compares c:forEach and ui:repeat and lists some typical issues:

[Roger Keays, 2007. c:forEach vs ui:repeat in Facelets](https://rogerkeays.com/jsf-c-foreach-vs-ui-repeat)

---

**Update:**
There's the [ice:panelSeries](http://component-showcase.icefaces.org/component-showcase/docs/tld/ice/panelSeries.html) component which iterates over a given collection of objects.

```
<ice:panelSeries var="item" value="#{myList}">
   <h:outputText value="#{item.printThisText}"/>
</ice:panelSeries>
```